# Cannot display JSON result in AJAX succcess

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My ajax code looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "JSON",
    url : "index.php",
    success : function(data){           
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(data[i].1_assigned_accepted);
        }
    }
})
```

Now `console.log(data[i].1_assigned_accepted);` is giving me error, even though i have `1_assigned_accepted` as column name in my table. jQuery doesn't consider **1_**. How to resolve this?

Comment: try using .done instead of success

Comment: add an extract of your json as well, possibly console.write(data) to see what you're getting back vs what you expect to get back?

Comment: check whether you are accessing it properly..can you give the response

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: can you post what `index.php` returns

Comment: You can't start a variable with a number, change it to `assigned_accepted_1` and it should start working for you.

Comment: Parse it using JSON.parse()

Comment: @NickSurmanidze, OP has used the success parameter, not the success() function which has been deprecated, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi That's what setting the `datatype: JSON` does for you, you don't have to parse it yourself.

Comment: My problem is with the column name of my table.. If i have column name abc, Then i can easily access its value like `data[i].abc` . So here i have `1_abc` so `data[i].1_abc` doesn't work.

Comment: I have answered your question, hopefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
console.log(data[i].["1_assigned_accepted"]);
```

Comment: @RhysBradbury Actually, he does not need to include var i = 0. Try if yourself: for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { console.log(i); }, the rest of your answer is "tips" he doesn't need to fix his code. My answer works.

Comment: `console.log(data[i].["1_assigned_accepted"]);`, you dont need the extra `.`. And just because it runs does NOT mean its acceptable JavaScript. Im pretty sure his request would return a HTTP error because `contentType` isnt defined.

Comment: They aren't just 'tips'. They are valid improvements and standard best practises.

Comment: @RhysBradbury That's something for the OP to decide to practice later-on. Although they're valid best practices and standards, solving the issue at hand instead of focusing on superfluous is more effecient

Comment: @RhysBradbury It is, and a simple answer to their problem will help them overcome the issue they're facing to continue growing as a developer and finding new issues to research or ask solutions to, however flooding them with information on standards they really don't need to follow to get the job done doesn't help them in this specific scenario. Like I said, the guidance you gave does give people a better idea of what standard code practices are out there, but this is more for their manager to follow up on in code-reviews and not for us to dictate. Some companies do things their way regardless

Answer (score 1):

Try to use bracket form.

```
console.log(data[i]['1_assigned_accepted']);
```

Comment: Beat you by 9 seconds :P

Answer (score -1):

To fix your code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "index.php",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); //test to see if we get something back
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]['1_assigned_accepted']);
        }
    }
});
```

The difference OP and mine is assignment of `i=0;` -> `var i = 0;` and using brackets for getting the value.

Some Notes:

When doing a post you usually send data using the `data:` option. (remember to `Json.stringify(input)`). When posting you may need more options:

```
function postJson(url, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: successCallback,
      error: errorCallback
  });
}
```

Notice there's `contentType`, `dataType` and `data` being used here. You usually want all of these when doing a `post`.

Invoke like so:

```
var data = { name: 'Rhys' };
postJson(
  'index.php',
   data,
   function(responseData) {
     console.log(responseData);
   },
   function(err) {
     console.error(err);
   }
);
```

Another point:

You are assuming that your response object is an array, you could test using `instanceof`.

I hope this helps,

Rhys